# OpenCL device side enqueue kernel & local memory

Tags: c, opencl

I'm trying to use local memory inside a device-side enqueued kernel.

My assumption that any locally-declared array is visible across all work items in the work group.
This is proven to be true when I use local memory on kernels that are called from the host-side, but I'm running into problems when I use a similar setup on device-side enqueued kernels.

Is there something wrong with my assumption?

Edit:
My kernel is below:
My goal is to sort the FIFO pipe into 3 buffers.  The problem is that my work items have a limited view scope, and I'm trying to write the buffers into another pipe.

```
int pivot;

int in_pipe[BIN_SIZE];
int lt_bin[BIN_SIZE];
int gt_bin[BIN_SIZE];
int e_bin[BIN_SIZE];


reserve_id_t down_id = work_group_reserve_read_pipe(down_pipe, local_size);
//while ( is_valid_reserve_id(down_id) == false){
//  down_id = work_group_reserve_read_pipe(down_pipe, local_size);
//}
//in_bin[tid] = -5;
if( is_valid_reserve_id(down_id) == true){
    int status = read_pipe(down_pipe, down_id, lid, &pipe_out);
    work_group_commit_read_pipe(down_pipe, down_id);

    pivot = pipe_out;
    pivot = work_group_broadcast(pivot, 0); 

    work_group_barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
    work_group_barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);    
    in_pipe[tid] = pipe_out;        
    //in_bin[lid] = in_pipe[tid];

    int e_count = 0;
    int gt_count = 0;
    int lt_count = 0;       

    if(in_pipe[tid] == pivot){
        e_count = 1;
    }
    else if(in_pipe[tid] < pivot){
        lt_count = 1;
    }
    else if(in_pipe[tid] > pivot){
        gt_count = 1;
    }

    int e_tot = work_group_reduce_add(e_count);
    e_tot = work_group_broadcast(e_tot, 0);
    int e_val = work_group_scan_exclusive_add(e_count);     

    int gt_tot = work_group_reduce_add(gt_count);
    gt_tot = work_group_broadcast(gt_tot, 0);
    int gt_val = work_group_scan_exclusive_add(gt_count);   

    int lt_tot = work_group_reduce_add(lt_count);
    lt_tot = work_group_broadcast(lt_tot, 0);
    int lt_val = work_group_scan_exclusive_add(lt_count);           

    //in_bin[tid] = lt_val;
    work_group_barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
    work_group_barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    if(in_pipe[tid] == pivot){
        e_temp[e_val] = in_pipe[tid];
        //in_bin[e_val] = e_bin[e_val];
        //e_bin[e_Val] = work_group_broadcast(e_bin[e_val], lid);
    }
    if(in_pipe[tid] < pivot){
        lte_temp[lt_val] = in_pipe[tid];
        //in_bin[lt_val] = lt_bin[lt_val];
    }
    if(in_pipe[tid] > pivot){
        gt_bin[gt_val] = in_pipe[tid];
        //in_bin[gt_val] = gt_bin[gt_val];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, not wrong. Local variables are declared and used across whole work-groups device-side too. They won't be shared with the parent kernels, though.

What exactly are you doing?

Comment: This is OpenCL 2.0, in case it was ambiguous.  I'm taking the contents of a pipe, and I'm trying to perform specific writes to a local array.

From what I've seen, only 1 element of the FIFO pipe is visible to a single work item, from the way I'm interfacing with it.  

I've declared 3 arrays, and I'm writing to specific locations on those arrays based on what the popped result is, essentially sorting the FIFO pipe into 3 bins.

Comment: You should be able to see multiple pipe elements in the work-item, but there is no order in the pipe so you can't guarantee which work-item will get which value. I'm not sure what of your code is local memory. The code looks fine. You shouldn't have to use barriers around workgroup functions but that wouldn't break it.

Comment: My question was more about the abilities and limitations of pipes, namely the pipe infrastructure.  I wanted to create a dynamic tree structure out of pipes, which involved branching, and device-side pipe creation.  Pipes are memory objects, like buffers, and cannot be created on the device-side just yet.  From what I've seen in the AMD demo code, the best that pipes can do is form a long chain, reusing the pipes at each stage by swapping the __read_only with __write_only, and vice-versa.

Comment: I would also have to counter the statement that pipes have no ordering.  One can use the index as the write-order, in the write_pipe call.  Of course, I would love to be proven wrong on both fronts.

Comment: There is no order between reservations. Within a reservation you can use the index to address but it is bounded by the number of packets in the reservation. You're right, you cannot allocate pipes on the device side, but you can pass them around. Just be careful to correctly order the child kernels because the pipes don't support concurrent read and write.

Comment: Agreed.  One can reuse pipes.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The working solution to my question is:

Pipes cannot be created on the device side.  What I tried to accomplish was to make a dynamic tree structure, involving branches.  OpenCL pipes simply cannot do that, as pipes are still memory objects, created on the host-side.  There is no current way in the specifications to create memory objects.

Pipes, however, can be used in a dynamically-recursive method, albeit the recursion cannot deviate, and must occur in a linear fashion.  Please consult the sample code found in the AMD APP SDK sample code packs for more details.  Specifically, please look at the Device Enqueue BFS example.